# Laravel for update is not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have made a patch request to a controller and noticed that `$request` does not have a value within the update function.
Here is my update function:

```
public function update(Request $request,  $id)
{   


    $this->validate(request(), [
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'f_name' => 'required',
        'm_name' => 'required',
        'g_name' => 'required',
        's_name' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'mobile' => 'required|number|min:10',
        'job_title' => 'required',
        'orgnaization' => 'required',
        'email'=>'required | email',


    ]);

    $user = User::where('id', $id)->first();
    $user->f_name = $request->input('f_name');
    $user->m_name =  $request->input('m_name');
    $user->g_name =  $request->input('g_name');
    $user->s_name =  $request->input('s_name');
    $user->user_id =  $request->input('user_id');
    $user->address =  $request->input('address');
    $user->job_title =  $request->input('job_title');
    $user->mobile =  $request->input('mobile');
    $user->orgnaization =  $request->input('orgnaization');
    $user->email =  $request->input('email');
    $user->save();
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Done!');
}
```

}

web.php

```
Route::get('ManageUsers','UserController@index')->middleware('Admin');
Route::get('ManageUsers/Delete/{id}','UserController@destroy')->middleware('Admin');
Route::get('ManageUsers/Edit/{id}','UserController@editUsers')->middleware('Admin');
Route::PATCH('ManageUsers/Edit/{id}/update',[ 'uses' => 'UserController@update'])->middleware('Admin');
```

Comment: why dont you make a resource instead
Route::resource('ManageUsers', 'UserController');

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with my view Also I am considring making resource instead of normal patch. thanks to  adh.ranjan